# Backward and forward compatibility with Avro schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

We are using registryless Avro schema for Kafka message So we have our custom Avro converter
Since we don’t have schema registry available

The issue is that when we upgrade the schema with new elements, the old schema is not backward or forward compatible

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Kafka is an implementation detail

If the reader schema is not compatible with the writer schema, then the Avro deserialization will fail. There's nothing you can do to fix that other than use a different schema.

You now know why having a Registry that's able to perform compatibility checks *before putting data into Kafka* is important

Comment: Please find this link below https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html.  Here you can make schema as full transitive and perform incremental changes on schema w/o breaking older schema for Kafka.how can we perform the same with our custom Avro converter and w/o schema registry

Comment: That compatibility logic only exists as part of the Registry... You're welcome to look at the source code and copy it out

Comment: Thanks , my question is more on that how part of it

Comment: Are you asking me to link you to the source code? I personally can't explain the logic of how it works